# Сортировка ломается на 3 проходе, что не так делаю?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Вот код, но почему-то он в итоге сортирует не так как хотелось бы. Подскажите пож-та в чем беда. Если не сложно, то в рамках текущего использованного уровня(без функций и тд), тк я пока только изучаю азы...

```js
var array = [4, 2, 1, 3, 6];
var max;
var swap;

for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 2; i++) {
  max = array[i];
  for (var j = 1; j <= array.length - 1; j++) {
    if (array[j] > max) {
      max = array[j];
      swap = array[i];
      array[j] = swap;
      array[i] = max;
    }
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: `var j = i; ...`

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Для общего развития: а почему если я указываю j =0, то не работает опять? 
ведь j=i тождественно j=0 тк i = 0

Comment: Так это на первой итерации оно равно 0, а дальше уже меняется.